# How do i go about stopping my rotation at a certain point on an axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

im currently working on a simple baseball game. What trying to do is have the player be able to swing the bat backwards to "charge up" power so to speak and then when button is released he will swing the bat forward at a speed equal to the amount of power stored up.

This is all well and good, but my problem is i need to stop the motion of the bat when he reach a certain point on the y-axis, and im a bit unsure how to go about doing this as i cannot just tell it to stop rotating after a set time as the bat wont reach the front point at the same time every time due to the difference in speed each swing might have.

Anyway here is the code ive written so far:

```
public int rotateSpeed = 50;
public float AmountOfPowerChargedUp = 0;

void Update() 
{


    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))    
    {
        AmountOfPowerChargedUp += 5f;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
        Debug.Log(AmountOfPowerChargedUp);
    }


    if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0)) 
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * AmountOfPowerChargedUp * Time.deltaTime);
```

// if(reached 266 on the y-axis stop rotating) <-- This is what im not sure how to achieve

```
    }   

}

private void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.Label (new Rect (50, 15, 250, 25), "AmountOfPowerChargedUp: " + AmountOfPowerChargedUp); // Tallene er mål på størrelsen og placering
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just get EulerAngle, and simply check if Y component is bigger than 266?